# Google Maps setCenter()

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm using google maps. In my code i've used setCenter() function. My problem is that marker is always located on top left corner of map area (not at the center). Please tell me how to resolve it?

My piece of code is

```
lat = 46.437857;
lon = -113.466797;

marker = new GMarker(new GLatLng(lat, lon));


var topRight = new GControlPosition(G_ANCHOR_TOP_RIGHT, new GSize(20, 40));
map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl3D(), topRight);
map.setCenter(new GLatLng(lat, lon), 5);

map.addOverlay(marker);
```

Comment: if you posted some of your code it is likely to help

Comment: @hotcoder: Can you also show us the `<div>` of the map canvas, and if possible the full JavaScript part that initializes everything. It looks like there is something wrong, somewhere else.

Comment: in image above u can see top left corner, there is marker at London

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
 function resize() {
        var map_obj = document.getElementById("map_canvas");

      /*  map_obj.style.width = "500px";
        map_obj.style.height = "225px";*/
        if (map) {
            map.checkResize();
            map.panTo(new GLatLng(lat,lon));
        }
    }

<body onload="initialize()" onunload="GUnload()" onresize="resize()">
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
</div>
```

Comment: V3.
Thanks for the help.
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(x, y));

Answer (score 30):

@phoenix24 answer actually helped me (whose own asnwer did not solve my problem btw). The correct arguments for setCenter is

```
map.setCenter({lat:LAT_VALUE, lng:LONG_VALUE});
```

[Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngLiteral)

By the way if your variable are lat and lng the following code will work

```
map.setCenter({lat:lat, lng:lng});
```

This actually solved my very intricate problem so I thought I will post it here.

Answer (score 6):

For me above solutions didn't work then I tried

```
map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng));
```

and it worked as expected.

Comment: All the above didn't work for me, but this. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

I searched and searched and finally found that ie needs to know the map size.
Set the map size to match the div size.

```
map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas2"), { size: new GSize(850, 600) });

<div id="map_canvas2" style="width: 850px; height: 600px">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

in your code, at line

```
map.setCenter(new GLatLng(lat, lon), 5);
```

the setCenter method takes just one parameter, for the lat:long location. Why are you passing two parameters there ?

I suggest you should change it to,

```
map.setCenter(new GLatLng(lat, lon));
```

Comment: @phoenix24: `setCenter()` takes an optional zoom parameter, so there's nothing wrong with that: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GMap2.setCenter

Comment: @Daniel I think the optional paramater has been deprecated in the GoogleMapsV3 APIs. http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/v3/reference.html

Comment: Yes, actually the entire API changed in V3. The OP is using v2 however. This can be deduced from the "classes" starting with the `G` prefix. The v3 uses the `google.maps` namespace instead.