# Google Maps V3 setCenter Moves pos to top left

Tags: google-maps, jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3

I've read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2773263/google-maps-setcenter-problem) but the problem persists. Basically when I use `setCenter` on a LatLng, the marker is always in the top left of the map, just out of sight.

The marker is placed in the correct spot, but when I use either `panTo` or `setCenter` the marker is always hidden top left, just out of sight.

It works fine within Safari on the desktop, but the problem occurs on the iPhone. I am using Javascript, jQuery, jQuery Mobile.

Is there a fix for this?

```
<div id="map_canvas" style="height:280px;"></div>
googleMap.get('map').setCenter(latLng);
```

### googleMap is defined as:

```
$('#map_canvas').gmap({ 'disableDefaultUI': true, 'callback': function (map) {
    googleMap = this;
```

### Adding markers:

```
googleMap.addMarker({ 'position': new google.maps.LatLng(markers[t].latlng.$a, markers[t].latlng.ab), 'label': markers[t].label}, function (map, marker) { })
```

Comment: My guess: you have a zero width div for the map. But can't tell for sure as you haven't provided enough context.

Comment: Indeed, why didn't you set a width for `map_canvas`?

Comment: do you have multiple divs with data role-page in your html??