# Correct setcenter for google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have issue same as Issue 1448: Bug: API v3 needs a checkResize function (or equivalent) where my map not fully loaded and not center.
I have marker but after resize it moved to top left (hidden). Just move a little bit and u can see it.

Pls read post #23 for more info.

Live Demo:
http://bestjob.my/mod/Gmap_Geo/

I need to add setcenter to resize code below:
Code:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[href="#tab2"]').click(function(e) {
        setTimeout(initialise, 500);
    });

    function initialise() {
        var myMap = document.getElementById('map-myid1');
        google.maps.event.trigger(myMap, 'resize');
    };
});
```

Pls help to give me correct setcenter code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Maps setCenter() problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2773263/google-maps-setcenter-problem?rq=1)