# how to center the marker in google map? for 1000 record

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, dictionary, maps

I m fetching record from database base on current location, once I get the result i want to display the markers in the center so user don't need to move the map left right,
see the below image I have fetch 1000 record and it's show few in the center for the rest user need to move the map, see the below image,[image: goo]

here is my code,for initializing the map

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){

    var locations = {!!$doctors!!};


      const uluru = { lat:29.6400599, lng:-95.1668589 };

  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 15,
    center: uluru,
  });

  

  $.each( locations, function( index, value ){

const contentString =
    '<div id="content">' +
    '<div id="siteNotice">' +
    "</div>" +
    '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Details</h1>' +
    '<div id="bodyContent">' +
    "<p><b>Name:</b>"+value.name+"</b></p>" +
        "<p><b>MI:</b>"+value.mi+"</b></p>" +
    "<p><b>Medical Group:</b>"+value.practice_name+"</b></p>" +

        "<p><b>Phone:</b>, "+value.phone1+"</b>,</p>" +
    "<p><b>Fax</b>, "+value.fax1+"</b>,</p>" +
    "<p><b>Office Hours</b>, "+value.office_hours_1+"</b>,</p>" +

    "<p><b>Gender:</b>"+value.gender+"</b>,</p>" +
    "<p><b>Specialty:</b>"+value.primary_specialty+"</b></p>" +
    "<p><b>Board Certification/Facility Accredetaion:</b>"+value.board_certified+"</b></p>" +
   
    '<p>Facility Quality Data, <a href='+value.facility_quality_data+"'>"+
    "Facility Quality Data</a> " +
    ".</p>" +
        "<p><b>Address:</b>"+value.address1+"</b></p>" +

    "</div>" +
    "</div>";



     const infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString,
  });
  const uluru = { lat:parseFloat(value.Latitude), lng:parseFloat(value.Longitude)};
  const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: uluru,
    map,
    title: "Click here to view details of this doctor",
  });
     marker.addListener('click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
});

 });

  });
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2773263/google-maps-setcenter

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Maps setCenter()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2773263/google-maps-setcenter)